# Ember mixin as interfaces

Tags: ember.js

Can an Ember object use mupltiple mixins ? I think mixin is equivalent to interface in Java and in that case there should be provision to implement many mixin here -

```
App.Movie = Ember.Object.extend(App.FirstMixin, { .. });
```

If there is a SecondMixin as well , how can this object use that ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, sure it can. Have a look at [the code of the prominent ArrayController Class](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/array_controller.js#L97) for instance:

```
Ember.ArrayController = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(Ember.ControllerMixin,
  Ember.SortableMixin, {
  ....
});
```

And actually mixins **can be used as an equivalent to Java interfaces**, but a mixin is not limited to an interface definition. Mixins are a mean of multiple inheritance and **can also provide properties and method implementations** to the classes that are using them. So the notion of an interface is to limited for the mixin concept.